# Rails5: form remote - trigger submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form with remote option set.
I need to trigger the submit programmatically.

In Rails 4 I use `$('form').trigger('submit.rails')` and it works as expected.
In Rails 5 (5.1.2 and 5.0.4) triggering that event causes a standard submit (formdata, not AJAX).

For Rails staff 'submit.rails' is not part of Rails project, see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29811#issuecomment-315844048)

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Form code:

```
<%= form_with(model: post, remote: true) do |form| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've never heard of `submit.rails`. where does it come from?

Comment: Seems like this is a part of [`jquery-rails`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/47d15123e27ca22f642b7befaeb152339f5d466a/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js#L476). Can you ensure that this is included in your project?

Comment: Yes, it's included in my project

Comment: Why don't just use `$('form').submit()`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale because it causes a standard submit (formdata, not AJAX)

Comment: It will submit the form via `ajax` if `remote` is set to `true`

Comment: can you please post the form`

Comment: The tests that I made are on the link of the issues. The form is generated using scaffold. The submit is made by AJAX only when clicking on the submit button. BTW I update my answer

Comment: Can you verify that your `application.js` has `//= require jquery_ujs`? Following your steps in GitHub issue, I get your problem (you never stated 'add that line as a step', when I looked at the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) gem page, they mention you need to do this and everything started working for me

Comment: My application.js is:
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .

Comment: yeah, try adding `//= require jquery_ujs` after your `//= require jquery`...I can toggle your error on and off by including or removing that line

Comment: @SimpleLime: you are right :) make it as answer and I mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments thread, the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) gem needs to be included into your `application.js` file for things to work properly

> The jquery and jquery-ujs files will be added to the asset pipeline and available for you to use. If they're not already in app/assets/javascripts/application.js by default, add these lines:
>
> ```
> //= require jquery
> //= require jquery_ujs
> ```

It appears you're missing the second line

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Following your reproduction steps in the GitHub issue, and then making sure that line is included fixes the issue for me, and `$('form').trigger('submit.rails')` in the javascript console starts submitting as

> Processing by PostsController#create as JS